# Create a directory with command expansion: quoting issue

Tags: shell, zsh

I have the following typical problem with my workflow: I want to copy some files to a directory that is not yet created. Mostly I do it in this way:

```
cp *.JPG /some/path/[oops, I recalled that the directory does not exist, ^C]
mkdir /some/path/newdir
cp *.JPG /some/path/newdir
```

To avoid this I created a script called `md` that creates a directory and returns its path:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p "$*"
echo "$*"
```

Then my workflow looks like this:

```
cp *.JPG `md /some/path/newdir`<TAB><ENTER>
```

When I press `<TAB>`, `md` is executed, the directory created and line with backticks substituted with its path, then I can press `<ENTER>` and execute `cp`.

Everything works fine unless I have spaces in the path of the new directory. In that case, after expansion, I have unescaped spaces on my command line.

I tried to overcome this by putting the path in quotes like this (in `md`):

```
echo "'$*'"
```

But in this case after expansion I have quotes escaped:

```
cp *.JPG \'/Users/user/temp/one two three\'
```

Is there any way to avoid escaping of quotes on command expansion in zsh? I tried `$()` and different types of quotes (`"` instead of `'`), but nothing works.

Of course, I can just do it in this way:

```
cp *.JPG "`md /path/with spaces`"
```

But I want to save a couple of keystrokes, if possible.

Comment: Have you considered just working around it by making a `mdcp` that first creates the target directory? You wouldn't need to write any quotes when using it, not even backticks. (If you want it to work for multiple commands, you could do `md cp ..` or `md mv` instead and create the last parameter before running the command)

Comment: @thatotherguy good idea, I'll think about it if won't be able to solve problem with quotes...

Comment: Maybe just `rsync *.jpg /some/new/dir/`? `rsync` will create the destination directory if it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve that is by creating a script/function for the whole thing (I'd prefer a function, because you're presumably going to be using it only from an interactive shell session):

```
#Ensures Targetdir exists and then copies into it
#Usage: cp_t Targetdir FlagsAndFiles...
cp_t()
( 
    targetdir="$1"; shift || return 1
    [ -d "$targetdir" ] || mkdir -p "$targetdir" || return 1
    exec cp "$@" "targetdir"
)
```

(This is POSIX too, so you should be able to use it with other POSIX shells as well.)